# converting SQL query to HQL

Tags: java, sql, hql

I need to convert this SQL query to HQL

```
select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            routemaste0_.ROUTE_ID as col_0_0_,
            routemaste0_.ROUTE_CODE as col_1_0_,
            routemaste0_.START_PLACE_ID as col_2_0_,
            routemaste0_.END_PLACE_ID as col_3_0_,
            routemaste0_.IS_ACTIVE as col_4_0_,
            routemaste0_.LINKED_ROUTE as col_5_0_
        from
            OPRS_ROUTE_MASTER routemaste0_
            inner join OPRS_ROUTE_HALTS routehalts0_
                 on routemaste0_.route_id = routehalts0_.route_id
        where routehalts0_.PLACE_ID = '51'
        order by
            routemaste0_.ROUTE_ID ASC  )
```

I tried this way

```
SELECT    rm.id , 
          rm.routeCode , 
          rm.startPlaceId , 
          rm.endPlaceId , 
          rm.active , 
          rm.linkedRoute 
FROM      RouteMaster rm  
          INNER JOIN  rm.routeHalts AS rh 
WHERE     rm.id = rh.routeId  
          AND  rh.placeId = :PlaceId  
ORDER BY  rm.id  ASC
```

but not getting the expected result. My concern is i need the `inner join on` condition to execute.

Can some one help me

Comment: Is there an association in your mapping between `OPRS_ROUTE_MASTER` and `OPRS_ROUTE_HALTS`?

Comment: Post your entities, their mapping and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the reason of problem can be that route_id is not a primary key in any of tables. Thats why I recommend you to try Theta style join in this case:

```
SELECT  rm.id , rm.routeCode , rm.startPlaceId , rm.endPlaceId , rm.active, rm.linkedRoute 
FROM RouteMaster rm, RouteHalts rh
WHERE rm.routeId = rh.routeId AND rh.placeId = :PlaceId  
ORDER BY  rm.id  A
```

And in your variant of HQL query you don't need *rm.id = rh.routeId*  part in where condition.

Comment: At last i used the theta style and reworked on other conditions. Thanks dimas. :)